# Can you make NavigateUrl direct to a page with a dynamic parameter appended to the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms, web

I am trying to append something from an object onto a URL so that I can make a parameter out of it. The goal is to do something like this:

articleview.aspx?Name=AwesomeSauce

Where I could use the Name parameter on the page I'm directing toward.

I have some code here:

```
<asp:hyperlink Text=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %> NavigateUrl="ArticleView.aspx" </asp:hyperlink>
```

But I'm not sure how I could add the "?Name={variable}" part on the end. Can anyone help me out? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ArticleView.aspx?Name={0}", Eval("SomeName"))%>' ... />
```